# Exactly which JOGL files to use for windows

Tags: java, opengl, netbeans, jogl

I don't know **Exaclty** wich **file** I should get. I think I finally found the site but there like a list of 500 different types of files on there.

I'm using **NetBeans IDE** for my programming, so that's Java code and I would like a step by step (Clear to understand) tutorial on exactly which files I should currently download(Include exact link if need be), How to set it up(the jars if there are any because I tend to see a lot of zip files w/ no jars in them), and how to set it up in Netbeans.

If anyone has an Idea, write the solution down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions to setup JOGL for Netbeans IDE with some screen captures and some detailed explanations are on our wiki:
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#NetBeans_IDE

It's a lot better than tinkering our JARs on Maven Central with the risk of using the wrong files.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so after more in depth digging, I found not only the JOGL jars, but every single jar out there in one site. To top it off, more than 75% of the jars had a modified date in 2015, so there all up to date here's the website,

http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|jogamp

**Caution** Be sure to really read what your downloading b/c cause on potential mismatch and you could potentially screw up your computer!